# Disable crash reports of Firefox in Linux

Tags: firefox, crash-reports

I've got an old PC running Linux and Firefox is creating crash reports with a rate of 1 MB per min. This clogs my system and fills my hdd, which has about 2GB of free space.

How can I completely stop the creation of crash reports that reside in the folder:

```
.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports/pending
```

Answer (score 1):

In .profile just added

```
export MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_DISABLE=1
```